# Formação das palavras “pai” e “mãe”: terão sido diminutivos de “padre” e “madre”?

Tags: etimologia

“Pai” e “mãe” vêm do galaico-português *padre* e *madre*, que por sua vez vêm do latim *pater, patris* e *mater, matris*. A minha pergunta é se *pai* e *mãe* terão começado por ter sido palavras familiares usadas com e por crianças (como *mamã, mamãe* atualmente) ou se resultaram de evolução fonética comum a outras palavras da língua portuguesa.

A pergunta está feita. Vou agora só apresentar a motivação. Isto é uma ideia que me tem andado na cabeça já há tempo, desde que observei que os britânicos, mesmo adultos, tratam tipicamente os pais por *mum* e *dad* e não por *mother, father*. Mesmo quando falam de eles é mais comum empregarem *mum* e *dad*. Em Portugal praticamente só se usa *mãe* e *pai*. Pouco se ouve *mamã, mãezinha, papá, paizinho*. Uma busca no Google parece indicar a mesma coisa para o Brasil: *pai* – 164 milhões; *papai* – 21 milhões; *mãe* – 87 milhões; *mamãe* – 15 milhões (*papá* não é comparável porque apanha as línguas castelhana, francesa e italiana). Por comparação: *father* – 880 milhões; *dad* – 698 milhões.

A primeira coisa que me ocorreu foi que *mum/mom* e *dad* são mais curtas, portanto mais práticas, que *mother* e *father*, e encurtar *mãe* e *pai* não daria grande resultado. Depois ocorreu-me que *pai* e *mãe* pudessem ter começado por ser os equivalentes de *dad* e *mum*, coexistindo primeiro com *padre* e *madre*, acabando por os eliminar depois. Espero que alguém possa lançar alguma luz sobre esta questão.

Comment: Talvez haja essa característica da língua em simplificar as palavras mais usadas. Como você, anteriormente vossa mercê, pai e mãe podem ter participado desse mesmo processo

Comment: @tdmsoares Não me tinha lembrado do vossa mercê. É possível que tenha sido um fenómeno parecido, sim. O meu chamava à minha avó *nha mãe* (de *minha mãe*). Acho que em Cabo Verde ainda se fala assim.

Comment: O *D* e o *R* trocavam-se com frequência, e o *D* intervocálico no português perdiu-se. Dali, teríamos «mae» e «pae», e a nasalização em *mãe* por começar com consoante nasal.

Comment: @guifa Conheces muitos casos de perda do *D* intervocálico? Nós conservamos muitos. Teríamos que ter perdido o *R* também.

Comment: @Jacinto a perda do D não foi tão extendida como a do L ou do N, mais por exemplo temos as formas de vós (*-ades* -> *-ais*) e algumas outras palavras (*veder* -> *ver*). Mas só quis dizer que se perdeu nestas palavras, não como regra geral. Se o R se trocasse com o D, teríamos *madde*, e os consoantes duplos nas línguas ibéricas ocidentais se perderam foneticamente (mas no português não até o séc. XX na escritura), assim que teríamos *made* e dali *mae*. A rama leonesa também apresenta as formas *mai* e *pai* na modernidade, assim que não foi só o galaicoportuguês que tive essa evolução

Comment: @guifa E qual é o estatuto de *mai* e *pai*. São as únicas formas? Também existe *madre* e *padre*?

Comment: @Jacinto no mirandés, usa-se *padre* só em contextos religiosos (*Padre Nuosso*). No asturiano, existem três formas (*madre, mai, ma*, e *padre, pai, pá*), *padre/madre* normalmente só se usam nos sentidos não parentescos (*madre* é, por exemplo, a última fila no xadrez), e quando se usa parentescamente sem dúvida é por influência castelhana. As formas diminutivas formar-se a base de *pa(i)* e *ma(i)*

Comment: Na minha terra se fala *"pade"* em vez de *"pai"* em rezas também, mas só pelos mais idosos. Todos os dias ouço meu avô rezando o *"Pade Nosso"* em vez do Pai Nosso. Quanto ao sacerdote religioso, também se usa "pade" em vez de "padre". Um sacerdote bastante famoso e conterrâneo meu, o [padre Cícero](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padre_C%C3%ADcero), é chamado popularmente de "Pade Ciço" ou "Padim Ciço" (onde *"padim"* é a abreviação do diminutivo *"padinho"*, e *"Ciço"* é a abreviação de *"Cícero"*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De facto, essa é uma explicação frequentemente avançada. Por exemplo, [nesta resposta no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/fenomenos-foneticos-ocorridos-de-patrem-a-pai/29548) de Edite Prada:

> O vocábulo **pai**, que já ocorre no séc. XIII, ainda que pontualmente, tem uma evolução obscura, digamos assim. A versão mais corrente explica a origem da palavra a partir de *padre*, tendo como origem a generalização de uma pronúncia infantil, em que se verifica a síncope do *r*: **pade*. Seguir-se-ia a síncope do *d* e a alteração do ponto de articulação da vogal. Teríamos, pois, globalmente, *patrem* > *patre* > *padre* > **pade* > *pae* > *pai*.

Note-se o *evolução obscura*. O mesmo diz o Houaiss, referindo-se também a "linguagem infantil":

> prov[avelmente] objecto da evolução do lat[im] vulg[ar] *patre-* > *padre* > **pade* > *pai*, por infl[uência] da linguagem infantil, que se manifesta ainda nas f[ormas] de redobro *papá*, em Portugal, e *papai*, no Brasil; ver *pater-*; f[ormas] hist[óricas] sXIII *pai*, sXIII *pay*, sXV *paay*, sXV *pae*, sXV *pere*.

E por aí adiante; pesquisando `pai padre "linguagem infantil"` no Google Books encontram-se muitas outras passagens no mesmo sentido. Não se veem, contudo, argumentos, e, quando há citações, todas elas vão parar às [*Lições de Philologia Portuguesa*](http://www.archive.org/stream/liesdephilol00vascuoft#page/88/mode/2up) de José Leite de Vasconcelos, que não mais diz do que «provavelmente por influencia da lingoagem infantil».

Só consegui encontrar [um argumento em Carolina Michaëlis de Vasconcellos](https://books.google.nl/books?id=eKZHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q&f=false) (*login* com conta do Google parece ser precisa):

> Na bôca das crianças *padre* transformou-se (como lembrámos já) em *pade* pela dificuldade que para elas há na pronúncia do grupo consonântico *dr*, e mesmo na de *r* simples, um dos fonemas últimos que, em geral, aprendem a balbuciar. *Pade* passou depois a *pá-e* pela queda de *d* intervocálico — seguramente na bôca de párvulos nas suas primeiras tentativas de falar; e *pa-e* ditongou-se. Do século XVI em diante a forma *paí* passou, dos círculos familiais à literatura — ao passo que *padre* se conservou em linguagem eclesiástica.

Em minha opinião, o argumento é bastante especulativo (note-se o «seguramente» na passagem de Carolina de Casconcellos, a qual, é bem sabido, é código em círculos académicos para «não tenho prova alguma de que isto seja verdade»). No [Corpus Informatizado do Português Medieval](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/) (registo necessário), temos de facto ocorrências de *pai* em cantigas de escárnio e maldizer do século XIII, [por exemplo](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/corpus/texto.jsp?t=d&id=18942):

> Nom se vaia de Sevilha
>   ca será gram maravilha
>   quant’achar, se o nom filha,
>   ca assi fez[o] seu **pai**;

Não há qualquer indicação de uma natureza infantil da palavra, mas claro  que (1) a amostra é pequena, que (2) pelo século XIII poderia já não ter esse caráter e que (3) os contextos em que essa natureza fosse evidente não ocorrem facilmente.

Silveira Bueno, em *Estudos de Filologia Portuguêsa*, apresenta ainda uma [derivação distinta](https://archive.org/stream/estudosdefilolog01buen#page/198/mode/2up/search/197):

> Formados com a vibrante *r*: *br*, *cr*, *dr*, *fr*, *gr*, *pr*, 
>   *tr*: conservam-se, exceto *dr* que vocaliza o *d* em *i*: [...]
>   *patrem* = *padre* = **paire* = **paie* = 
>   *pai*; *matrem* = *madre* = **maire* = **maie* = *mai* = 
>   *mãe*. Estas duas modificações explicamos pelo provençal e pelo francês, pois, as formas *paire*, *maire* são as 
>   mesmas que hoje encontramos escritas *père*, *mère*. A 
>   queda da vibrante *r* intervocálica é rara, mas, já vimos 
>   em *proram* = *proa*. As formas *paie*, *maie* ainda hoje 
>   ouvimos na linguagem infantil no Brasil, perdendo-se 
>   depois o *e* final por apócope desde que o *i* forma ditongo com a precedente. Temos confirmação dêstes nossos 
>   desenvolvimentos na palavra *fratrem* = *fradre* = *fraire* 
>   = *freire* = *frei* e também *frade*. E ainda em *cathedram* 
>   = **cadedra* = *cadeira*, isto é, a vocalização do *d* em *i*.

Não compreendo bem o que quer o autor dizer com «ouvimos **ainda hoje** na linguagem infantil»; especialmente quando marca *paie* como forma hipotética. Em todo o caso, o autor defende que fenómenos semelhantes ocorreram (separadamente) em outras palavras, o que tiraria força à hipótese de que a transformação se deve a linguagem infantil.

Comment: Excelente. Portanto temos *pai* no sXIII e eu ainda ontem encontrei *padre* no sXV. Portanto as duas formas coexistiram pelo menos três séculos. Agora poderiam ser familiar/oficial ou popular/culto (as duas coisas não se excluem). A mim agrada-me a ideia de o nosso *mãe* e *pai* terem sido o *mamã, mamãe, papá, papai* de outros tempos.