# Porque é que viemos a ter ditongo nasal em «mãe», mas oral em «pai»?

Tags: etimologia, fonologia

[*Mãe*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/m%C3%A3e) e [*pai* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pai) vieram do latim *mater, matris* e *pater, patris*, via *madre* e *padre* do galaico-português. Vejam  esta [pergunta sobre a possível influência da linguagem infantil nesta evolução](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/forma%C3%A7%C3%A3o-das-palavras-pai-e-m%C3%A3e-ter%C3%A3o-sido-diminutivos-de-padre-e-madre).

Ora o que me faz espécie é que o mesmo conjunto ***adre*** tenha dado em ditongo nasal ***ãe*** em *mãe*, mas em ditongo oral ***ai*** em *pai*, que foi até ao século XIX comumente grafado *pae*.

Curiosamente no galego existe a mesma diferença entre as pronúncias de [*mai*](http://academia.gal/dicionario/-/termo/busca/mai) e [*pai* (Real Academia Galega com reprodução áudio)](http://academia.gal/dicionario/-/termo/busca/pai), apesar de a grafia não o assinalar.

Terá sido mero acidente, ou há alguma razão fonética para esta divergência?

Comment: Seguramente pelo M inicial.

Comment: @guifa Seguramente sabes algo que eu não sei. Como é que é isso do M?

Comment: É verdade que é mais comum a nasalização regressiva (sobretudo nas línguas românicas), na qual uma consoante que segue um vogal a produz.  Mas também é possível uma progressiva, que é quando uma consoante que precede a vogal causa a sua nasalização.  Alguns exemplos no português são *minha*, *mãe*, e *muito*.

Comment: @guifa Escreve então uma resposta. Conheces alguma fonte acessível a leigos? Gostaria de aprender mais sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nasalização de *a* em *mãe* é provavelmente resultado de um processo de nasalização progressiva, do mesmo tipo da que ocorre em *muito*, só com a diferença de que a ortografia portuguesa não permite fazer explícita a nasalização do ditongo *ui* (**mũito*?). Aparentemente não existem muitos estudos sobre esse fenômeno ainda, mas tem pelo menos um, preliminar, que você pode ler aqui: [Progressive Vowel Nasalization in Brazilian Portuguese: A Preliminary Analysis](http://www.academia.edu/20205673/Progressive_vowel_nasalization_in_Brazilian_Portuguese_A_preliminary_analysis). (Eu só tive tempo de dar uma lidinha por cima.) Tem a ver não apenas com a ocorrência deste tipo de nasalização mas também com a dinâmica física da sua produção nas diferentes vogais e a percepção dela pelos falantes.