# Why do people in Portugal pronounce "e" as "ei" or "a" before "ch", "j", "lh" and "nh" (as in fecho, veja, abelha, tenho) but as "e" otherwise?

Tags: português-europeu, pronúncia, fonologia

A funny thing happens in European Portuguese accents. It has been described in [this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/quando-%C3%A9-que-e-se-pronuncia-%C9%90j). One of the sounds the letter ***e*** represents in Portuguese is /e/ (as in *v**ê***). However when a stressed ***e*** pronounced by Brazilians and many speakers in southern Portugal as /e/ is followed by a post alveolar fricative at the start of the next syllable, /ʃ/ (as in *fe**ch**o*) or /ʒ/ (as in *se**j**a*) most speakers in Portugal will pronounce it as /ɐj/ (as in the English word *b**ay***.)

For instance (follow the audio links to Forvo), *fecho* is pronounced [/’fɐjʃu/](https://forvo.com/word/fecho/#pt) by a Portuguese, but as /’feʃu/ by a Brazilian.

And *seja* is pronounced [/’sɐjʒɐ/](https://pt.forvo.com/word/seja/#pt) by user Flowerchild from Portugal, but as /’seʒɐ/ by at least two Brazilians. However I’d say user Sirasp from Brazil pronounces it very close to /’sɐjʒɐ/ as well.

And then when the ***e*** pronounced by Brazilians and many speakers in southern Portugal as /e/ is followed by the palatal lateral approximant /ʎ/ (as in *espe**lh**o*) most speakers in Portugal will pronounce it as /ɐj/, /ɐ/ or something in between. Hear [*espelho* in Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/espelho/#pt) pronounced by people from Portugal and Brazil. But if is followed by the palatal nasal /ɲ/ (as in *te**nh**o*) it will be pronounced by most speakers in Portugal as /ɐ/. Hear [*tenho* in Forvo](https://pt.forvo.com/word/tenho/#pt).

The stressed ***e*** will remain /e/ or /ɛ/ for all speakers when followed by other consonants. Now is there a phonetic reason why an ***e*** normally pronounced as /e/ would change into /ɐj/ or /ɐ/ when followed by /ʃ/, /ʒ/, /ɲ/ or /ʎ/, but remain /e/ when followed by other consonants? Do those particular consonant sounds sort of invite or make it easier for the /e/ to turn into /ɐj/ or /ɐ/?

Answer in whatever language you prefer. As long as it is English or Portuguese, that is.

---

### Em Português

Há uma coisa curiosa nos sotaques de Portugal. Foi descrito [nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/quando-%C3%A9-que-e-se-pronuncia-%C9%90j). Um dos sons que a letra ***e*** representa no português é /e/ (como em *v**ê***). Contudo quando um ***e*** tónico pronunciado por Brasileiros e muitos falantes no sul de Portugal como /e/ é seguido por uma fricativa pós-alveolar no início da sílaba seguinte, /ʃ/ (as in *fe**ch**o*) or /ʒ/ (as in *se**j**a*), a maioria dos falantes em Portugal pronunciam-na como /ɐj/ (como na palavra inglesa *b**ay***.)

Por exemplo (sigam os links para ouvir as palavras pronunciadas no Forvo) *fecho* é pronunciado [/’fɐjʃu/](https://forvo.com/word/fecho/#pt) por uma portuguesa, mas /’feʃu/] por um brasileiro.

E *seja* é pronunciado [/’sɐjʒɐ/](https://pt.forvo.com/word/seja/#pt) pela Flowerchild de Portugal, mas /’seʒɐ/ por pelos menos dois brasileiros. Mas parece-me que a brasileira Sirasp pronuncia *seja* um pouco como /’sɐjʒɐ/ também.

E o ***e*** pronunciado por Brasileiros e muitos falantes no sul de Portugal como /e/ é seguido da lateral aproximante palatal /ʎ/ (como em *espe**lh**o), a maioria dos falantes em Portugal pronunciam-na /ɐj/, /ɐ/ ou algo no meio. Ouçam [*espelho* no Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/espelho/#pt) pronunciado por brasileiros e portugueses. Mas se for seguida da nasal palatal ɲ/ (como em *te**nh**o*), a maioria dos falantes em Portugal pronunciam-na /ɐ/. Ouçam [*tenho* no Forvo](https://pt.forvo.com/word/tenho/#pt).

O ***e*** tónico continua para todos os falantes /e/ ou /ɛ/ quando seguido por outras consoantes. Ora haverá alguma razão fonética para um ***e*** normalmente pronunciado /e/ passar a ɐj/ ou /ɐ/ quando seguido de ʃ/, /ʒ/, /ɲ/ or /ʎ/, mas permanecer /e/ se seguido por outras consoantes? Há alguma coisa nestas consoantes particulares que convide ou facilite a mudança do /e/ em /ɐj/ ou /ɐ/?

Responde na língua que preferires. Desde que seja Português ou Inglês.

Comment: There are several peculiarities in pt-PT pronunciation of certain morphemes.  Some people I've met pronounce the first "o" in "todo" as /ou/.  or they pronounce "pra ela" as something like /praiela/ or "peixe" as /paish/.  Very often the Portuguese omit weak vowel sounds such as first "e" in "competentes". Escuse my not using the IPA (I would if this were an answer).

Comment: @Centaurus Yes, but this pronunciation of ***e*** as /ɐj/ ou /ɐ/ occurs only before those four consonant sounds; so there must be something special about them.

Comment: Great question, but where is English "bay" pronounced similar to [bɐj]? I've always heard English /e/ as [ej] or [ɛj], at least here in northeast USA. (My ears don't distinguish those two.) Could a better example be the vowel in *like* or *nice* (as opposed to the [aj] of *I* or *bye*)? (My sense is there's still a difference, but that might be clos*er*?)

Comment: @Dan maybe my ears are fooling me. Here's how I perceive it. Brazilians and Portuguese pronounce *ei* differently. Compare [*lei* pronounced by pathgs and aimae here](https://pt.forvo.com/word/pt/lei/#pt). I hear English *lay* as Portugal's *lei*; but maybe that's [UK *lay* only](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lay_1?q=lay). I don't here *lei* as English *lie*. But [Infopédia renders *lei* as /lɐj/](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/lei). I've seen it like that elsewhere too. (continues)

Comment: But now listening to [the vowel table here](https://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm), [lɐj]doesn't sound like a good representation. Perhaps the best would be [lɜj] (for Portugal), where [ɜ] is as in English /bird/. Then even if *ei* is [ej] in Brazil and [ɜj] in Portugal, and we tell the difference, they don't make distinguishing minimal pairs. So maybe I could just represent it /ej/. I'd like to give the phonetic representation because, in principle someone who doesn't know Portuguese might still be able to answer this question.

Comment: @Jacinto I completely forgot that this is the pronunciation of "ei" in Portugal (now I see that you mention this in the title), so I was trying to make a (false) distinction between [ɐj] and "ei". I can hear that the UK pronunciation of *lay* is closer to the Portuguese *lei*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article on Portuguese, in central and southern Portugal /e/ can be **centralised** before palatal sounds (and by context this includes post-alveolar sounds). That is, /e/ will become [ɐ] before /ʃ/, /ʒ/, /ɲ/, /ʎ/. The article about Portuguese dialects also says that

> In and near Lisbon, /ei̯/ and /ẽi̯/ are pronounced [ɐi̯] and [ɐ̃i̯],
>   respectively. Furthermore, stressed /e/ is pronounced [ɐ] or [ɐi̯]
>   before a palato-alveolar or a palatal consonant followed by another
>   vowel.

Consider the well-known fact that many dialects (both in Brazil and Portugal) turn syllable-final [s] to [ʃ]. Also note that in Northeastern Brazil as well as in Rio de Janeiro speakers **diphthongize** stressed vowels before [ʃ] when word-final (therefore *mas* [majʃ], *fez* [fejʃ], *nós* [nojʃ]) - and in some other contexts too, as I've heard.

Not all phonetic changes have to have a "reasonable" explanation, but in this case, inserting a yod [j], which is a palatal approximant, between a vowel and a palatal (or post-alveolar or alveolo-palatal) consonant, seems rather reasonable.

Combine both tendencies (centralization and diphthongization of stressed vowels in the vicinity of the alveolo-palatal point of articulation) and you have an explanation of why those consonants might trigger /e/ → [ɐj].

Comment: So the [ j ] is sort of on the way from [ɐ] to palatal, post-alveolar and alveolo-palatal consonants?

Comment: @Jacinto Well, /j/ *is* palatal, like /ɲ/ and /ʎ/, and /ʃ/ and /ʒ/ are post-alveolar, so they're all pronounced pretty close to each other inside the mouth. So a sequence like [ɐjʒ] (as in *seja*) means you have central vowel + palatal approximant + post-alveolar fricative. Each sound grades neatly into the next.

Comment: I wonder whether you have any explanation for the centralization of /e/ before /ʃ/, /ʒ/, /ɲ/, /ʎ/. That’s probably the main question. And does your explanation for the insertion of the /j/ requires the previous centralization? Because in Portugal most people centralize all /ej/ into [ɐj] or maybe [ɜj] (see comments to the question above), so I take this as a given; but we centralize /e/ only before /ʃ/, /ʒ/, /ɲ/, /ʎ/. And also before /ɲ/ the /e/ does not get the yod; it becomes just [ɐ] or [ɜ]; to some extent that’s also true before /ʎ/. (continues)

Comment: So, if your argument for the insertion of the yod works with [e], then we could have /ʃ/, /ʒ/ and maybe /ʎ/ triggering /e/ → [ej]; and then [ej] → [ɐj], because we do that for all /ej/. That would just leave /e/ → [ɐ], [ɜ] unexplained. I have a more comprehensive description of the pattern  /e/ → [ɐj] , [ɐ] in an answer to [this question](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/quando-%C3%A9-que-e-se-pronuncia-%C9%90j); it is in Portuguese, but I see you understand it well :)

Comment: Also, would you like to have a go at [this other question of mine](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3860/porque-%C3%A9-que-viemos-a-ter-ditongo-nasal-em-m%C3%A3e-mas-oral-em-pai?noredirect=1&lq=1); there are a few comments there that sort of make sense to me, but there's no full answer.

Comment: @Jacinto I don't have an explanation; indeed, my answer was basically a summary of what you had already noticed, confirming that it does happen and was not just an anecdote of yours. As I said, phonetic changes don't have to have an explanation, or better - the explanation is always *ad hoc* and not deterministic (if sound changes were deterministic we'd expect all languages to change in the same way, which is obviously untrue even though tendencies do exist). (cont.)

Comment: ...It may be that yod-insertion between /e/ and /ɲ/ is ongoing, or it may be that nasalization blocks or hides it, or something else entirely. That yod-insertion also seems weak before /ʎ/ could point to the fact that maybe it started with only post-alveolar /ʃ/ and /ʒ/ (as in those dialects of PT-BR) and only then it began to propagate to the palatals.

Answer (score 3):

/e/ is a high-mid front vowel: [image: Portuguese Vowel Chart]

Notice the position of of your tongue when you pronounce the sound /e/.

Now, notice the position of your tongue when you pronounce the consonants /ʃ/, /ʒ/, /ɲ/ and /ʎ/, and the vowel /i/.

These sounds make your tongue assume a position close to the position it must have when pronouncing the /e/ sound. That's why they are special.

European Portuguese appears to dislike to pronounce a vowel followed by a sound that is to close to that vowel.

Not only the /e/ became an /ɐj/ or /ɐ/ before /ʃ/, /ʒ/, /ɲ/, /ʎ/ and /i/, but the /i/ may also change to an /ɨ/ before these sounds.

Also, notice that the diphthongs /ej/ and /ow/ don't exist anymore in standard European Portuguese.

Comment: Queres dizer /e/ muda para /ɐj/ ou  **/ɐj/**? Tens  /a/. Já me tinha passado pela cabeça, que o /j/ fica ali próximo do /e/ e daquelas consoantes. Já o /i/ passar a /ɨ/ , isso também pode acontecer antes de /z/ (vizinho, dizer). O /u/ também pode passar a  /ɨ/ ou  desaparecer antes de /ʎ/ (mulher, colher). Isso é capaz de ser o fenómeno mais geral de redução/cancelamento de certas vogais átonas.

Comment: Sim, era /ɐj/ ou /ɐ/. No caso de vizinho pode ser explicado por ser seguido de sílaba com outro som i, tal como em ministro, príncipe, militar, civil, etc. Mas não excluo a hipótese de também acontecer antes de /z/ visto que também é feito com a língua debaixo do palato, daí talvez resultar em pronúncias como «dezer».