# O que significa a expressão Tia-Mãe?

Tags: expressões, português-europeu

Eu estava assistindo um desenho "Marvel’s Spidey and His Amazing Friends" com a dublagem em Português de Portugal. Quando reparei que Peter Parker (*Homem aranha*) chama a sua tia "May Parker/Aunt May" de **Tia-Mãe**.

Fiquei com duvida, mesmo porque nunca tinha ouvido a expressão antes sobre o que realmente quer dizer: **Tia-mãe**.

Alguém consegue me explicar oque significa esta expressão  ?

Comment: Eu diria que foi erro técnico de tradução/dublagem... Isso é bastante comum, na real (erros de tradução/dublagem). Mas como não vi esse desenho, fica difícil de opinar...

Comment: AFetter, viste isso num canal de televisão em Portugal? Se nos pudesses indicar o canal e dia e hora (mais ou menos), talvez pudéssemos encontrá-lo e ver. Ou ouvir. Já agora, confirma (ou corrige) por favor que querias dizer *tia-mãe*, que foi como todos nós entendemos o *tia-mae* que tu escreveste.

Answer (score 5):

O nome da tia do Peter Parker é [*May*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aunt_May), cuja pronúncia inglesa é [*m**êi***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/May#Pronunciation). Em Portugal, as palavras terminadas em *ei*, como *lei* e *rei*, têm esse *ei* falado como [*ae*](http://portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=122859), parecido com *ãe* em *mãe* sem usar o nariz; por exemplo, *rei* é *râe*, *lei* é *lâe*. É provável que, por isso, o dublador tenha dito *May* como *Mâe*, notando-se que ***Mâe* ≠ *mãe***.

Talvez o dublador tenha feito isso para regionalizar o nome, talvez porque assim lhe é mais natural falar. Eu não sei.

Comment: Também pensei nisso. Agora não me parece é que tenha havido qualquer tentativa de "regionalizar". Muitos portugueses, talvez a maioria, certamente os da região de Lisboa, falando inglês, naturalmente pronunciam *may* bastante mais como *mâi* do que como *mêi*, que aliás é basicamente como muitos ingleses pronunciam. Nota que "*May*, cuja pronúncia é *mêi*" está incorreto; o teu link, dá a pronúncia no alfabético fonético internacional, /meɪ/, e a realização do fonema /eɪ/ varia entre mais ou menos *âi* (muitos ingleses) e *êi* (muitos norte-americanos).

Comment: Basicamente o pessoal na região de Lisboa pronuncia *(eu) sei* como este [*say* britânico* (pronúncia azul)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/say_1?q=say). Já os brasileiros se aproximam mais, creio, da pronúncia vermelha (mesmo link).

Comment: @Jacinto, admito que vi a diferença que vi era pouca. Para mim, ambos estavam falando “sêy”. Desculpa pela demora. Eu só me lembrei agora.

Comment: Este ponto é secundário, mas olha que o Dan, americano, concorda que a pronúncia britânica de *lay* se aproxima de *lei* em Portugal (vê comentários a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/why-do-people-in-portugal-pronounce-e-as-ei-or-a-before-ch-j-lh-an); e tendo eu um vez dito que *milk* era *leite*, um inglês começou a tocar no relógio e a dizer que era *late*. >>

Comment: Mas o essencial do meu ponto é que a pronúncia *mâi* de *May* não é uma adaptação deliberada; é como um português pronuncia naturalmente, independentemente de se aproximar ou não de qualquer pronúncia nativa. Portugueses, e brasileiros e outros, a menos que falem mesmo muito bem inglês, em muitos casos falam com sons do português aproximados do inglês e não com os verdadeiros sons do inglês. Por exemplo, a maioria dos portugueses e brasileiros que eu conheço pronunciam o /æ/ de *bat, bad* etc. como *é*, de modo que tornam *bat* e *bet* homófonos.

Comment: Então para ti, *bad* = *bed* = *badge*? É pá, o "brasileiro" é português com açúcar.

Answer (score 3):

Tens a certeza que não confundiste o que ouviste? Esta é uma expressão que eu também nunca ouvi mas parece-me ser o caso de teres confundido *May* por *Mãe*, daí transformaste no teu cérebro *"Tia May"* em *"Tia Mãe"*.